# Loading files without instantiable classes with autoloader

Tags: php, autoloader

This is the structure of my project:

```
- project
-- src
--- class1.php
--- class2.php
--- class3.php
--- class4.php
--- class.php
- autoload.php
```

This is how my autoloader (`autoload.php`) looks:

```
<?php

/**
 * @param string $class The fully-qualified class name.
 * @return void
 */
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    // project-specific namespace prefix
    $prefix = 'ProjectName';

    // base directory for the namespace prefix
    $base_dir = __DIR__ . '/src/';

    // does the class use the namespace prefix?
    $len = strlen($prefix);
    if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
        // no, move to the next registered autoloader
        return;
    }

    // get the relative class name
    $relative_class = substr($class, $len);

    // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
    // separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
    // with .php
    $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';

    // if the file exists, require it
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    }
});
```

Now, I have a file (`class.php`) which contains all configuration parameters for the rest of files located in `src` directory (constants, interface, abstract classes and some global functions). What's the best way to load it without interrupting whole process?

Comment: Autoloaders load classes. If your configuration code is outside a class, you can't autoload it. I.e., you can't autoload a file that contains global functions. See [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for the accepted way to construct your source tree. You should have one class or one interface or one abstract per file.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I know for PSR-4, I used it for autoloader; so I should put constants and other functions in one class to or I can define them globally in their own namespace?

Comment: That's a matter of opinion and will vary by project needs. Personally, I try to avoid defining anything the global namespace. Sometimes I'll drop global functions into a `Utility` class or similar, so they'll be autoloaded when you call them via `Utility::func()`.